# Finding the Upper and Lower Bound From a Triangular Region.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Integrate $f(x,y)$ = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ over the triangle region with vertices $(0,0), (1,0),(1,\sqrt{3})$

I get the first part converting polar to rectangular. I do not understand after that point how to use the unit circle to find the bounds if I could then I would solve the question.

$\iint r*r\,drdϴ$ according formula $\iint f(x,y)= (rcosϴ,rsinϴ)r\,drdϴ$

I drew this picture to illustrate the problem.
http://tube.geogebra.org/m/euWAiHj9

Comment: What is the equation of a line?

Comment: Do I use the slope formula $\frac{y2-y1}{x2-x1}$ ?

Comment: If that would help you, but I am asking for the equation here.

Comment: Why do we need the slope for this problem?

Comment: Don't lines slopes?

Comment: I am basically asking you if you could write out the equation of a line, particularly the slanted line in your picture.

Comment: I found the slope of the two points $(0,0),(1,0)$ is 0... So $y =0$?

Comment: I am asking for the *slanted* line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find your bounds for $d\theta$ and then find the bounds for $dr$ as a function of $\theta$. The angle of your triangular region changes from $0$ to $\arctan(\sqrt{3}) = \pi/3$, and your $r$ changes from $0$ to the line $x = \sqrt{3}$, or $r = { \sqrt{3} \over \cos \theta}$, so the iterated integral should be $\\
\int _0 ^{\pi /3} \int _0 ^{\sqrt{3} / \cos \theta } r ^2 dr d\theta$

Comment: sorry my mistake I forgot to put a comma after the 1 for the third point so it should be $1/cosϴ.$. Quick question why is it over $cosϴ$?

Comment: since $x = r\cos \theta$ when converting from rectangular to polar, you substitute that into $x = 1$